# What permissions are required for app catalog on sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, office365-apps

Hello exactly what permissions are required to upload apps on a app catalog in sharepoint

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/distribute-an-access-app-in-your-app-catalog-or-the-sharepoint-store-0360b4e8-2767-422c-8edf-5da55b31a394?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Here says site collection admin permissions

But here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/manage-the-app-catalog

Says site owners or designers?

Anyone know which one is right?

Answer (score 2):

In order to upload apps in App Catalog. You need to add the account you are logged in as an admin on the app catalog site.

Step 1: Open Site Collections Admin Center

URL will look like this: https://yourcompany-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/SiteCollections.aspx

Step 2: Locate the App Catalog Site Collection, then click Manage Administrators

Step 3: Add Your Account as Site Collection Administrator

Step 4: Wait for a couple of minutes until the loader disappears

Thats it! You are good to go now

Answer (score 0):

To upload apps on a app catalog in sharepoint, site owners or designers will be enough. The first aritcle go to the app catalog through the sharepoint admin center which needs site collection admin permissions. If you know the url of app catalog, you can go to app catalog as site owners or designers.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Ali Raza's answer, the new SharePoint Admin Center (as on June 2022) has a slightly different flow and names.

**Prerequisite: you are a Company Administrator.**

1. Go to Site collection administrators. Here is the URL format: `https://{yourcompany}.sharepoint.com/sites/appcatalog/_layouts/15/mngsiteadmin.aspx`. If want to know how you get here, follow the steps below.

   1. Go to SharePoint Admin Center. URL format: `https://{yourcompany}-admin.sharepoint.com`.
   2. Go to "More Features" > Apps > Click [Open]
      [image: SP Admin - Apps settings]
   3. In the new window, go to "More Features" > "Site contents" > Click [Open]
      [image: Apps - Site contents]
   4. In the new window, click "Site settings"
      [image: Site contents - Site Settings]
   5. Under "Users and Permissions", click "Site collection administrators"
2. Add the appropriate "User", "Email" or "User Group" in the "Site Collection Administrators" text box.
   [image: Add Site Collection Administrator]
3. Click OK

Answer (score 0):

The URL in this post is a bit dated. The URL that is currently the correct one is:

https://yourcompany-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/siteManagement

Then click on the site collection name to edit permissions under the permissions tab.